# Prove that the properties are remain unchanged of the matrix...

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ integer matrix whose columns are pairwise distinct.
> Show that there is a row in $A$, whose removal results in an $(n − 1) \times n$
> matrix with the same property

Here is an argument

We can prove this statement by contradiction. Assume that there is no row in $A$ whose removal results in an $(n-1) \times n$ matrix with pairwise distinct columns. This means that for every row of $A$, the resulting $(n-1) \times n$ matrix obtained by removing that row has at least two columns that are identical.

Let's label the columns of $A$ as $c_1, c_2, \ldots , c_n$. For any row $i$ of $A$, let $A_i$ denote the $(n-1) \times n$ matrix obtained by removing row $i$ from $A$.

Since the columns of $A$ are pairwise distinct, there exist two distinct columns $c_i$ and $c_j$ of $A$. Without loss of generality, assume that $c_i$ appears before $c_j$ in $A$ (i.e., $c_i$ is to the left of $c_j$).

Consider the $(n-1) \times n$ matrices $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_n$ obtained by removing each row of $A$ in turn. Since $c_i$ and $c_j$ are distinct, there must exist a row $i$ such that the columns of $A_i$ corresponding to $c_i$ and $c_j$ are distinct. Let's call these columns $a$ and $b$, respectively.

Since $A_i$ has $(n-1)$ rows and $n$ columns, there must exist another row $j \neq i$ such that the columns of $A_j$ corresponding to $a$ and $b$ are the same. Otherwise, the $(n-1) \times n$ matrix obtained by removing row $i$ from $A$ would have pairwise distinct columns, which contradicts our assumption.

Let's call this common column $c$. Then, the $(n-2) \times n$ matrix obtained by removing rows $i$ and $j$ from $A$ has two identical columns (namely, $a$ and $c$), which contradicts our assumption that there is no row in $A$ whose removal results in an $(n-1) \times n$ matrix with pairwise distinct columns.

Therefore, our assumption must be false, and there must exist a row in $A$ whose removal results in an $(n-1) \times n$ matrix with the same property.

Is this in right way or give another solution!!!